# How can I do a maintainable and significant risk assessment in an organisation with thousands of assets?

Tags: risk-management, risk-analysis, risk

The problems I see with the typical risk assessment are as follows:

- Maintaining the list of assets updated
- Maintaining the status of the treatments updated and the risk level
  coherent with that.
- Maintaining the dependency of the assets in a way that irrelevant
  assets (like a server) have the real risk (due to the fact that that
  the server allows a critical process to run).

The problem I see is that when I finish the Excel the results are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

There are many commercial asset management solutions that auto-discover assets and their relationships such as Service Now.

Then the discovery scans run daily or weekly on a schedule to keep it up-to-date.

Of course, nothing is perfect so it has to be put directly into the shoulders of the server and app owners to on a recurring basis and after any change control to update or fix any incorrect data or add missing data in the inventory.

For example:

- a project can't go live until all systems, apps, and their relationships are updated
- a new pc or server cannot be deployed until it's in the inventory
- a system is decommissioned they must remove it from inventory

The risk assessor then should just be given access to the inventory but should not be required to maintain it